# Verilog Time delay calculation

Tags: verilog, timedelay

I am writing a very simple code for my project, all it has to do is calculate the time. I have two switches, A & B. All I want to do is start the time when the A is pressed and then stop it when B is pressed. Maybe I can store this time into a variable and then output the Var to a 7 segment! ( I only need the timing part, 7 Seg is OK)

I have no background in verilog, and can't get a lot of help online, can someone please give me a hint.

note: Apparently, It has to be in Verilog, and has to be in *.v format

Thanks,

Comment: Do you know how you want to measure time? I would think counting clock edges, you need to know the frequency if you want to turn it back in to seconds.

Comment: Why does it have to be in Verilog? And there are many, many Verilog resources on line...why don't you google "verilog stopwatch".

Comment: Why the hell would you give this a down vote??  .. Anyways, it's a CPLD project for my logic course! so it has to be Verilog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will start by recommending that you find a good guide to Verilog and have a look at that, you will also need to find a simulator to test your code.

Now assuming you are only measuring clock cycles between the button presses you need to start a counter on a and stop it on b. Possibly using and b to control a FSM, which in turn controls the counter.

Things to be carefully of are a and b are external and asynchronous they need to be put through meta stability flip-flops. Depending on the mechanical switches you may also need to add more denouncing to them.

I was going to add some code but since you do not know verilog it should be broken down into much smaller steps than giving you the full solution, which I feel would rob you of the learning experience.

If you just want to see some code for a Verilog Stop watch [simplefpga.blogspot.co.uk](http://simplefpga.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/to-code-stopwatch-in-verilog.html) seems reasonable.

As you are learning verilog a hardware description langage, first think about the problem and what you are trying to achieve. A Counter, a state machine. Then move on to implementing a basic version of what you need adding features as you require then.

May be a free running counter which overflows. A free running counter which stops at the max value. A counter which starts when a button is pressed, a counter which starts when a button is pressed and stops when another button is pressed.

Then you can ask questions much better suited to the Q&A format of the site. eg I am trying to implement a counter as part of a verilog stop watch, I am not sure how to imply functionality x.

Try not to be daunted by the language and if possible enjoy the process of learning new skills.

Comment: Thanks Morgan, I have developed the base of the program, ports, and etc.. I just didn't know how to 'start the clock', in Atmel or C I can use the internal clock/counters but I have no clue how to do this with CPLD, i.e counting falling edges and use the Freq to calc the time

Comment: Sorry I can not help with the clock generation on FPGA/CPLD I work with ASIC and I just get some one to build me a PLL or have access to the chips main clock.

Comment: @user1622997 Verilog questions are welcome here but for specific hardware CPLD questions you may get a better response on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/